# Enabling RBAC on Existing GKE Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, rbac

We have been running a cluster on GKE for around three years. As such, legacy authorization is enabled.

The control plane has been getting updated automatically, and our node pools are running a mixture of 1.12 and 1.14.

We have an increasing number of services, and are planning on incrementally adopting istio.

We want to enable a minimal RBAC setup without causing errors and downtime of our services.

I haven't been able to find any guides for how to accomplish this. Some people say just to enable RBAC authorization on the GKE cluster, but I assume that would take down all of our services.

It has also been implied that k8s can run in a hybrid ABAC/RBAC mode, but we can't tell if it is or not!

Is there a good guide for migrating to RBAC for GKE?

Comment: Is your control plane running on version 1.12 ?

Comment: @KoopaKiller the control plane is 1.14

Comment: The steps here might help you
 https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control.
I have recently set up minimal RBAC in my cluster which is running on version 1.14.
Also read here https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/hardening-your-cluster#leave_abac_disabled_default_for_110

Answer (score -1):

If you cluster is Regional you won't have downtime in your application when upgrade, but if your cluster is single-zonal or multi-zonal the best approach here is:

1. [Add a new node pool](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-pools#add)
2. [Cordon the old node pool](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#manual-node-administration) to migrate the applications to the new node pool
3. [Delete the old node pool](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-pools#deleting_a_node_pool) after all pods are migrated.

It is the safesty way to update your node pool (zonal) without downtimes. Please read the references below to understand in details every step.

References:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#reliability
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#interacting-with-nodes-and-cluster

Comment: this is a good guide for upgrading Kubernetes. However, this question is specifically about migrating from legacy authorization (ABAC) to RBAC on GKE.

Comment: I know, updating your cluster you will be able to set the rbac. Did you have a chance to test it? Reconsider the downvote if you haven't test it.

Comment: This question is not about upgrading Kubernetes. The version we are running fully supports RBAC, but it is disabled. This question is specifically about migrating to RBAC safely